# Compare same column of merged dataframe and append difference in a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes Df1 and Df2. I have merged Df1,Df2 on column a. Now I want to compare the same name columns of the merged dataframe and append in "miss_match" column if the values dont match.

eg:
compare b_PE with b_PS, c_PE with c_PS.
if the value of b_xx does not match and value of c_xx does not match then we will append mismatch column with b,c

similarly if value of b_xx match and value of c_xx does not match then we will append mismatch column with c

```
Df1
a   b   c
a   '1' 1
2   '2' 5
c   '3' 3

Df2
a   b   c
a   '4' 0
2   '2' 2
c   '6' 3

merged_df

a   b_PE    b_PS    c_PE    c_PS
a   '4'       '1'      0       1
2   '2'       '2'      2       5
c   '6'       '3'      3       3

expected result:

a   b_PE    b_PS    c_PE    c_PS    miss_match
a   '4'       '1'      0       1      b,c
2   '2'       '2'      2       5      c
c   '6'       '3'      3       3      b
```

Any suggestions on this will be very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) by `a` with `suffixes` parameters, then compare values for not match by [`DataFrame.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) with converting to numpy array because different columnsnames and get new column by matrix multiplication by [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) with columns names `b, c` (values before `_`):

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='a', suffixes=('_PS','_PE'))

df1 = df[['b_PS','c_PS']].astype(int).ne(df[['b_PE','c_PE']].astype(int).to_numpy())

df = df[['a','b_PE','b_PS','c_PE','c_PS']]

df['miss_match'] = df1.dot(df1.columns.str.split('_').str[0] + ',').str.rstrip(',')
    
print (df)
   a  b_PE  b_PS  c_PE  c_PS miss_match
0  a     4     1     0     1        b,c
1  2     2     2     2     5          c
2  c     6     3     3     3          b
```

More general solution with `MultiIndex` - not necessary specify columns names:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='a', suffixes=('_PS','_PE'))

df1 = df.set_index('a').astype(int)
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)

df1 = df1.xs('PS', level=1, axis=1).ne(df1.xs('PE', level=1, axis=1))
print (df1)
       b      c
a              
a   True   True
2  False   True
c   True  False

df['miss_match'] = df1.dot(df1.columns + ',').str.rstrip(',').reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   a  b_PS  c_PS  b_PE  c_PE miss_match
0  a     1     1     4     0        b,c
1  2     2     5     2     2          c
2  c     3     3     6     3          b
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but I have object columns also in my dataframe. Have edited the question, apologies for not making it earlier. 
could you help me with the same

Comment: @Jai - added `.astype(int)`, can you test?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using a `groupby` on the columns:

```
merged_df = df2.merge(df1, on='a', suffixes=('_PE', '_PS'))

group = merged_df.columns.str.replace('_.*', '', regex=True)
mask = merged_df.groupby(group, axis=1).nunique().gt(1).stack()
s = mask[mask].reset_index(level=1).groupby(level=0)['level_1'].agg(','.join).rename('miss_match')

merged_df.join(s)
```

output:

```
   a  b_PE  c_PE  b_PS  c_PS miss_match
0  a     4     0     1     1        b,c
1  2     2     2     2     5          c
2  c     6     3     3     3          b
```

Comment: Perfromance should be problem here. `groupby.nunique` is slow.

Comment: @jezrael it doesn't seems so slow, also I think it is more generic

Comment: @mozway - yes, agree, your is more generic. So changed my solution. With performance not agree double `groupby` also with `nunique` is slowier vs compared values in columns with `dot`. Best test in real data